# SQL query returns different results when index is dropped

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2000 SP4, I have a query

```
SELECT <fields no aggregates>
  FROM PS_VED_VCH_TAO5 A  
    ,PS_BUS_UNIT_TBL_AP B  
    ,PS_RT_DFLT_VW C  
    WHERE   A.PROCESS_INSTANCE = 594170  
    AND A.VAT_CALC_AMT <> 0  
    AND A.VAT_ENTRD_AMT <> 0  
    AND A.VAT_ENTRD_AMT <> A.VAT_CALC_AMT  
    AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT  
    AND A.VCHR_SRC <> 'PROC'  
    AND B.VCHR_VAT_MSG_OPT = 'E'  
    AND A.VAT_CALC_TYPE = 'E'  
    AND A.VAT_RCRD_INPT_FLG = 'Y'  
    AND A.VAT_RCRD_OUTPT_FLG = 'N'  
    AND C.FROM_CUR = A.TXN_CURRENCY_CD  
    AND (
            (C.TO_CUR = A.VAT_TOL_CUR_CD AND C.RT_TYPE = A.VAT_TOL_RT_TYPE)  
            OR 
            (C.TO_CUR = A.TXN_CURRENCY_CD  AND C.RT_TYPE = A.RT_TYPE  AND A.VAT_TOL_CUR_CD = ' '  AND A.VAT_TOL_RT_TYPE = ' ')
        )  
        AND C.EFFDT = 
        (  
            SELECT MAX(I.EFFDT)  
                FROM PS_RT_DFLT_VW I  
                    WHERE I.FROM_CUR = C.FROM_CUR  
                        AND I.TO_CUR = C.TO_CUR  
                        AND I.RT_TYPE = C.RT_TYPE  
                        AND I.EFFDT <= A.INVOICE_DT
        )  
        AND 
        (
            ((A.VAT_TOL_AMT < (((((A.VAT_ENTRD_AMT - A.VAT_CALC_AMT)) / ( C.RATE_DIV))) * ( C.RATE_MULT)))  
            OR 
            (A.VAT_TOL_AMT < (((((((A.VAT_ENTRD_AMT - A.VAT_CALC_AMT)) / ( C.RATE_DIV))) * ( C.RATE_MULT))) * ( -1)))
        ) 
        AND 
        (
            (A.VAT_TOL_PCT < (((((A.VAT_ENTRD_AMT - A.VAT_CALC_AMT)) / ( A.VAT_CALC_AMT))) * ( 100)))  
            OR 
            (A.VAT_TOL_PCT < (((((((A.VAT_ENTRD_AMT - A.VAT_CALC_AMT)) / ( A.VAT_CALC_AMT))) * ( 100))) * ( 1)))
            )
        )
```

PS_BUS_UNIT_TBL_AP has a unique clustered index on it. If the index is present, the above query results in a division by zero in

```
(A.VAT_TOL_PCT < (((((((A.VAT_ENTRD_AMT - A.VAT_CALC_AMT)) / ( A.VAT_CALC_AMT))) * ( 100))) * ( 1)))
```

despite the fact that the query explicitly excludes rows where VAT_CALC_AMT is zero.
If the index is dropped it doesn't ( and the query plan changes).
Also, if the query is changed to add a bogus condition "A.OPERATORNAME <> 'Non existent user'", it also works normally.

is this a bug in SQL or is something else going on?

Comment: Long story short: don't rely on short-circuiting. Just because something is eliminated in a where clause doesn't mean the where clause is evaluated first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create/drop the index, you also affect SQL Server Query Optimizer's plan created to service your query.

Have a look at this [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) item.

Basically, SQL Server is free to optimise the expressions in the SELECT clause ***prior to*** applying the WHERE conditions.  Not very intuitive, but someone decided it should do so.

Normally, to avoid divide by zero errors, I throw a NULLIF in there which is sufficient to get past the error while not really affecting the result (since the WHERE clause actually prunes them).

e.g.

```
(A.VAT_TOL_PCT < (((((((A.VAT_ENTRD_AMT - A.VAT_CALC_AMT)) / ( NULLIF(A.VAT_CALC_AMT,0)))) * ( 100))) * ( 1)))
```